How can I understand op-amp operation modes?
In the circuit below, the first op-amp of the circuit is used as a voltage comparator.  It is nearly the same circuit as that of the voltage follower op-amp.
How can I tell if an op-amp is used as an amplifier or as a voltage comparator?

Voltage follower opamp:


Where's the schematic from? Who's saying that the first opamp is used as a comparator?

Think you need to specify precisely which op-amp is "first"?

@Tyassin Opamp with 1u capacitor connected

I've labeled the op-amps in the first diagram so that we can talk about them:

Op-amp A is a voltage follower, just like the op-amp in your second diagram.  It is used to buffer the 1.65V signal generated by the voltage divider composed of the two 1M resistors and the 1µF capacitor.
Op-amp B is a sort of comparator.  It has a voltage divider to make 0.825V from the 1.65V reference. So long as the input to pin 3 of op-amp B is lower than 0.825V, the output (D1) of op-amp B will be low.  When the input exceeds 0.625V, the output of B will go high (3.3V.)
Op-amp C is also a sort of comparator.  It gets a voltage that is a weighted sum of 0.625V and 3.3V - that goes into pin 6 as the reference.  When the voltage from the photoresistor exceeds that voltage, the output of op-amp C (D0) will be high.
D1 and D0 are low while the photoresistor is dark.  As more light shines on it, D1 will go high.  As even more light shines on it, D0 will also go high.
The circuit in total is a comparator with two outputs.  Op-amp A is not a comparator.
An op-amp with no feedback will act as a comparator.  It isn't a good comparator, but it does the job in a lot of cases.

Unfortunately this doesn't answer the actual question "How can I tell if an op-amp is used as an amplifier or as a voltage comparator?" It just talks the Op through each of these particular circuits. That's not the same as explaining how to recognise a comparator circuit from an amplifier. You did write "An op-amp with no feedback will act as a comparator" but that doesn't cover their question - an op-amp comparator with hysteresis has feedback. Needs decent opening paragraphs explaining how they identify comparator and amplifier circuits. Downvoting until then, I'm afraid.

@TonyM: "An op-amp with no feedback will act as a comparator."  Besides which, the question was based on the false premise that op-amp A was a comparator.

I really don't understand your reply but I don't think you've read and understood my comment clearly before replying. It's ironic, as my comment says I don't think you read and understood the actual question clearly before answering :-) It asks how to recognise a comparator circuit from an amplifier in general, not in this specific circuit. I'll leave it with you to upgrade your answer or keep it as is.

I think, the "comparator" subject is purely a question of "necessary or sufficient". Of course, it is correct to say that "an opamp without feedback will act as a comparator". On the other hand - it is not correct to say that "a comparator is always an opamp without feedback".

Look for feedback (or its absence), which gives you four possibilities:

No feedback; gain is huge, making it behave like a comparator.

Positive feedback; gain is huge, so it's a comparator, but there's hysteresis too, forming a "schmitt trigger".

Negative feedback; depending on the way feedback is implemented, there are many things it could be. Purely resistive feedback will produce a linear amplifier with precisely controlled (and fixed) gain.

Both positive and negative feedback. Again, depending on the way feedback is implemented, this could mean anything. For example, sometimes you use negative feedback to set gain, and positive feedback for stabilisation against ringing or oscillation.


Sometimes you can't tell just by looking, what an-op-amp is supposed to be doing, and in those cases you just have to do the math.
You can identify positive feedback by the presence of a route (direct or indirect) for some fraction of the op-amp's output to make it back to its non-inverting input, shown left here:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
On the right there's no feedback at all, the output signal cannot influence the inputs in any way. The distinction is clear in a simulation, shown below. Input is a sinusoid, in blue. Orange is OUT1 showing hysteresis, where there is a difference between rising and falling thresholds, shown by the green markers. Brown is OUT2, just a plain comparator response:

If you can spot a way for an op-amp's output to somehow influence its inverting input, then you have identified negative feedback. There are two classic implementations:

simulate this circuit
Its clear in both designs that the op-amp's output (or some fraction of it, determined by the resistances) is able to influence the op-amp's inverting input. The left design is called an "inverting amplifier, because it amplifies and flips the signal upside-down, and it has gain \$-\frac{R_2}{R_1}\$. The circuit on the right amplifies but does not invert, and is called a "non-inverting" amplifier. It has gain \$1+\frac{R_4}{R_3}\$.
If \$V_{IN}\$ is a 2V peak-peak sinusoid (blue), the orange is the inverting (left circuit) output OUT1, and brown is the non-inverting output OUT2:

For more information about how those expressions are derived (and why one has a "1+" in it), and how these designs work, you might find this answer I wrote to be helpful.
The voltage follower is a special case of the non-inverting amplifier, above right. It has resistance values \$R_3=\infty\Omega\$ and \$R_4=0\Omega\$, so that gain is \$1+\frac{0\Omega}{\infty\Omega}=1\$:

simulate this circuit
That means your statement that the left-hand op-amp in your own circuit behaves like a comparator is incorrect; it does not. It isn't almost the same as a voltage follower, it's exactly the same, and therefore it is a voltage follower.
By contrast, for the right-most op-amp in your circuit, I see no way for its output to affect either its inverting or non-inverting input. It has no feedback, either positive or negative, and consequently that op-amp is a comparator.
In your circuit, the centre and right op-amps have no feedback. They are both comparators. The central one looks like it has negative feedback via the 500kΩ resistor and two 1MΩ resistors above it, but that's not the case. Look carefully and you'll see that the node marked "+1.65V" cannot change potential. It's always +1.65V because the voltage-follower top left is keeping it there. The center op-amp is unable to change that, and its inverting input is not at all influenced by its own output. Not even indirectly.
Just for completeness, you should be aware that sometimes negative feedback is difficult to spot, indirect, and may actually be applied to the non-inverting input:

simulate this circuit
This circuit employs a MOSFET to boost output current ability. We take feedback not from the op-amp's own output, but rather from the transistor stage's output. There's catch, though; the transistor stage actually inverts, due it being connected common-source. If we took its output and applied it to the op-amp's inverting input, the fact that it has already been flipped upside-down would cause feedback to become positive. To keep feedback negative, we unflip the flipped signal by feeding back to the non-inverting input instead. It's confusing, and I've been caught out many times by this.
Apart from that, a close examination will reveal that this design is very similar to the non-inverting amplifier from before. You may need to squint your eyes a bit, and shuffle some components around in your mind's eye, but you'll spot R4 and R3 in the same positions, forming a potential divider between the overall output and the op-amp's input. Therefore gain is still \$1+\frac{R_4}{R_3}=+3\$. Input is blue, output is orange:


I believe, the role of an opamp component in design is defined not by the configuration (feedback etc.) in the first place, but by the function it serves: whether the primary role is to amplify or to limit, even clip, the input signal. Therefore, only an experienced designer can determine whether the component is used as amplifier vs. comparator, by simple inspection.
Take, for example, the operational amplifier measurement circuit using the NULL method. The most pronounced feature of the DUT opamp configuration in this circuit is not the negative feedback (which, however hidden, is present here), but the fact that the attached networks make input differential signal small enough in order to enable the open-loop gain measurements: i.e., to operate as amplifier without direct feeding of the output to the inverting input via a passive component.
Still, the analysis of this "M.J. Watts 13/7/1997" circuit promises more interesting findings then the pedantry around amplifier/comparator definition. To simulate this circuit, I downloaded the TS95X model from the ST website. After some tinkering (replacing the line .SUBCKT TS95X 1 2 3 4 5 with .SUBCKT TS95X 2 1 4 5 3) the model is ready for use with LTspice. I composed the transient simulation incited by light falling on the light sensor, illuminance ever increasing from darkness to 10 lux for sweeptime seconds, resulting in the formula for LDR conductance G_LDR_conductance = Gdarkconductance + Gcellconductance · time / sweeptime. The shortcoming of this model is that the LDR conductance is taken to be proportional to the illuminance while this might be not the case. But conductance-vs-illuminance is ever increasing function, and the qualitative estimation is valid. The light dependent resistor (LDR) is simulated with time dependent resistor. The LDR parameters (dark resistance, cell resistance @10 lux) are taken from the NORP12 datasheet. The other details are clearly seen in the the circuit drawing.
With R8=68K and the NORP12 photoconductive cell, the noninv input voltage never crosses the ref voltage at the inv input of X2 comparator, so I took a liberty to decrease the R8 resistance to 6.8K. You run the simulation, and you see that the X2/X3 pair with their attached networks is an implementation of the window comparator, perhaps somewhat unusually presented in the circuit drawing.

The R10 pot value can be used to vary the window width.
Another oddity is the use of a BiCMOS chip as voltage follower and comparator components for this rather undemanding task, but it helps us demonstrate the subtlety of using opamp as comparator. Let us decrease time sweep from 1 s to 1 ms. We immediately (at least with my LTspice XVII version) encounter a convergence problem. Quite unexpectedly, Gear integration method drastically improves the convergence for the simulation parameters selected in this simulation:

We see that the transition times increase for both outputs D1 and D0 (window is widened) and the high value outputs become overlapping, even with this relatively low speed signals. The reason is that, however high speed are BiCMOS opamps, the TS95X opamp is an amplifier and so optimized for linear operations. To use it as comparator in time-critical applications, we have to add the circuitry preventing saturation of the TS95X output stage. To make life comfortable for circuit designers, there exist dedicated voltage comparator chips whose output stages use switching transistors. These chips are optimized for quick switching from one saturated state to another.
For a time-critical application we would use the light sensor other than the photoconductive cell: something like the photodiode. Therefore, the unrefined use of the opamp for thresholding is forgiving in this undemanding application.
